How can I decrease the leaf amount by branch size?
I am trying make a branch with leaves, but there are 2 problems:

I decrease the branch size by spline parameter, but the number of leaf Instances (Icospheres) doesn't change. How to decrease the leaf amount by the branch size?



I noticed that the leaf size is also decreased by the branch size, which is not what I want. How can I just decrease the leaf amount, and not its size?


Just take the Icospheres as Leaves. Input Lv3 is the leaf.


After downloading it seems you already found out that with a Realize Instances node you can reset the scale of the curves. The scaling which you use to define the length of the curves was also responsible for the size of the leaves.
Now for the amount: you plug a fixed value "Lv3 Count" into the Count of the Resample Curve node - of course then you have the same amount of leaves on every curve. To change that, you have to use a varying value - how and which value is basically to your own desire.
Possible examples:

Using the existing Float Curve as multiplier for "Lv3 Count" (set to 6 in the following image):


Subtracting the Index of the curves from "Lv3 Count" (set to 8 this time):


Using the Spline Length as multiplier for "Lv3 Count" (set to 5):


Or here just an example where the amount not simply decreases by 1 on each spline like the ones above, the Index to the Power of 0.5 (so it is the square root of the Index) subtracted from "Lv3 Count" (which is 8 again):



And these are just basic ideas, I guess you can come up with more mathematical operations to change the count like not only multiplying but also adding on top of it, or comparing with some value to make sure the amount never falls below a minimum etc. Just note that whatever value your calculations will produce, Blender will turn it into a floored integer for the Count (unless you round it up beforehand with a Ceil operation).

Thanks so much for your graceful solutions !  I learned and test them all, works very fine!
